# SOAP не работает в 1c

Tags: php, 1с, soap

Такая проблема, реализовал сервис SOAP на php. Составил описание wsdl. Проверяю в программе SoapUI все нормально грузится, все методы видны и так же на всяких онлайн тестерах. Но при передаче в 1с, не видно ни одного метода. WSКоллекцияОпераций возвращается пустой. Может кто сталкивался. Вот мой wsdl

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
                 xmlns:tns="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php" 
                 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                 xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                 xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
                 name="ExchangeWsdl" 
                 targetNamespace="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php">
        <types>
            <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php">
                <xsd:complexType name="Product">
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="ИДНоменклатуры" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="КачествоНоменклатуры" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="КоличествоНоменклатуры" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
                        <xsd:element name="ЦенаНоменклатуры" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true" />
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:complexType name="ProductList">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ТипОперации" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="ИДЗаявки" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="НомерЗаявки" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="ДатаСоздания" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="ИДКонтрагента" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="ЖелаемаяДатаПоставки" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="ИДГрузополучателя" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="СтатусЗаявки" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="Комментарий" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />

                        <xsd:element name="ProductList" type="tns:Product" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>

                <xsd:complexType name="OrdersList">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Заказ" type="tns:ProductList" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>

                <xsd:complexType name="statusResp">
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="ТипОперации" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="ИДЗаявки" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="СтатусЗаявки" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>


                <xsd:complexType name="statusRespList">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Статус" type="tns:statusResp" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>

                <xsd:complexType name="productsReq">
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="Код" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="ЭтоГруппа" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="Наименование" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="Родитель" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                        <xsd:element name="ПометкаУдаления" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true" />
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>

                <xsd:complexType name="ProductsRequestpList">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Номенклатура" type="tns:productsReq" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>

                <xsd:element name="Response">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="OrdersList" type="tns:OrdersList" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>

                <xsd:element name="ResponseStatus">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="statusRespList" type="tns:statusRespList" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>   

                <xsd:element name="ProductsResponse">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:boolean" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>

                <xsd:element name="ProductsRequest">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Номенклатуры" type="tns:ProductsRequestpList" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element> 

            </xsd:schema>
        </types>


        <!-- Привязка процедуры к сообщениям -->
        <portType name="ExchangeServicePortType">
            <operation name="getOrders">
                <input message="tns:getOrdersIn"/>
                <output message="tns:getOrdersResponse" />
            </operation>
            <operation name="getStatus">
                <input message="tns:getStatusIn"/>
                <output message="tns:setStatusResponse" />
            </operation>

            <operation name="setProducts">
                <input message="tns:setProductsRequest" />
                <output message="tns:setProductsResponse" />
            </operation>

        </portType>

        <!-- Формат процедур веб-сервиса -->
        <binding name="ExchangeServiceBinding" type="tns:ExchangeServicePortType">
            <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
            <operation name="getOrders">
                <soap:operation soapAction="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php#getOrders" />
                <input>
                    <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php"/>
                </output>
            </operation>
            <operation name="getStatus">
                <soap:operation soapAction="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php#getStatus" />
                <input>
                    <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php"/>
                </output>
            </operation>

            <operation name="setProducts">
                <soap:operation soapAction="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php#setProducts" />
                <input>
                    <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php"/>
                </output>
            </operation>

        </binding>

        <!-- Определение сервиса -->
        <service name="ExchangeService">
            <port name="ExchangeServicePort" binding="tns:ExchangeServiceBinding">
                <soap:address location="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/soap/exchangeservice.php" />
            </port>
        </service>

        <!-- Сообщения процедуры getOrders -->
        <message name="getOrdersResponse">
            <part name="Response" element="tns:Response" />
        </message>

        <message name="getOrdersIn">
            <part name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
        </message>

        <message name="setStatusResponse">
            <part name="Responses" element="tns:ResponseStatus" />
        </message>

        <message name="getStatusIn">
            <part name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
        </message>

        <message name="setProductsResponse">
            <part name="Responses" element="tns:ProductsResponse" />
        </message>

        <message name="setProductsRequest">
            <part name="Request" element="tns:ProductsRequest" />
        </message>
    </definitions>
```

Comment: Я как понимаю вы программно сервис создаете в 1С, а что будет если вы его через объект WS-Ссылки добавите, добавляется без ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

При работе со сторонними (не 1С-ными) web-сервисами в 1С у меня в своё время создалось впечатление, что 1С умеет работать правильно только со своими SOAP-сервисами. 
В частности, пробовали 1С на вход подать SOAP, сделанный на Java, ничего не вышло. Хотя SoapUI также отрабатывал.

Попробуйте лучше сделать на php REST-сервис и вызывать его из 1С. Это проще, чем вручную из 1С формировать правильные запросы для SOAP. Мы так в своё время поступили.